# Matlab - indexing

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a matrix `A` which is 21x1 and contains only ones and twos. 
Then I have a matrix `B` which is 6 * 600 matrix of numbers ranging between 0 and 21.

I want to generate a matrix `C` which is 6 * 600 matrix containing ones and twos such that:

If `B` matrix has a zero, matrix `C` should have a zero on that place. If `B` matrix has number 5, then matrix `C` should have the element on row 5 of matrix `A` and so on and so forth.

Please let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: It is unclear. You state that Matrix A has ones and twos only, and you state later: if A matrix has a zero? It has not since you said it only has ones and twos.

Comment: Just edited 30 seconds before your comment. Sorry about the typo. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Would be great to know why this was voted down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us generate some sample inputs:

```
A = randi(2,21,1);
B = randi(22,6,600)-1;
```

The output `C` will then be:

```
C = B*0;              %// preallocation + take care of the elements that need to be 0
C(B>0) = A(B(B>0));   %// logical indexing
```

The explanation of the 2nd line is as follows:

#### RHS

- `B>0` - return a logical array the size of `B` which has the meaning of whether this specific element of `B` is larger-than-0 value.
- `B(B>0)` - return the elements of `B` for which there are `true` values  in `B>0` (i.e. numbers that can be used to index into `A`).
- `A(...)` - return the elements of A that correspond to the valid indices from `B`.

Comment: @volcompt - you're welcome! Please be advised that it's better practice to provide a sample input/output with your question in addition to explaining it in words - this makes it easy (_possible_?) for others to test their solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
% Generate matrices fitting the description
A = round(rand(21,1))+1;
B = round(rand(6,600)*21);
C = zeros(6,600);

% Indexing impossible since zeroes cannot be used as index. So treat per element using linear indexing.

for ii = 1:(6*600)
   if B(ii) == 0
      C(ii) = 0;
   else
      C(ii) = A(B(ii));
   end
end
```

Although the piece of code could be optimized further this is the most clear way of creating understanding and speed is not needed if it's only this small matrix evaluated a limited number of times.

Comment: What about `A2=[0;A];` and then `C=A2(B+1);`

Comment: It's better to use [`numel()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) if you're explicitly iterating over all elements of a matrix.